# How to check if XSLT statement has been executed

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a `for-each` statement in my XSLT and an `if` condition inside it. I need to execute a piece of statement just first time when the `if` condition is true.

```
<xsl:for-each select="">
    <!-- if condition true -->
        <!-- DO SOMETHING -->
        <!-- if its the first entry in the if condition do something -->
    <!-- End If -->
</xsl:for-each>`
```

I am not able to use any variables to set the value to true false, since variables are constants in XSLT. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't talk about "the first time something is executed" with a functional language like XSLT. There is no defined or detectable order of execution. An xsl:for-each is not a looping construct, it is a mapping construct: it applies the same function (the for-each body) to every item in the input sequence, conceptually in parallel (and in some implementations, actually in parallel).

The item that you want to treat specially is therefore not the first item in processing order that satisfies some condition, but rather the first item in the input sequence that satisfies that condition.

You haven't stated the requirements precisely enough to know the ideal answer in your particular case, but some of the techniques at your disposal are:

(a) select the set of items to be processed more precisely by using a predicate in the select expression: `<xsl:for-each select="nodes[predicate]">`

(b) handle the first selected item specially by using `<xsl:if test="position()=1">`

(c) pre-evaluate the condition that makes some nodes special, and test for this in the for-each:

```
<xsl:variable name="special-nodes" select="...."/>
<xsl:variable name="first-special-node" select="$special-nodes[1]"/>
<xsl:for-each select="selected-nodes">
  <xsl:if test=". is $first-special-node">....
```

(That's 2.0 syntax; in 1.0 compare nodes using generate-id()).

(d) use recursion rather than for-each. A classic approach to recursion is that you write a template which takes a sequence as input. If there's at least one item in the sequence then the recursive template does something with it, and then calls itself to process the "tail" of the sequence, namespace all items other than the first. With this approach the items are indeed processed sequentially, and you can pass additional parameters with the recursive call to indicate, for example, that the first "special" item has already been found and processed.

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking too procedurally.  In XSLT, it helps to think declaratively instead.  Rather than trying to set a flag, test a condition against the input document.

For example, in your case, you can test the position of the item,

```
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
```

rather than set a flag.

You might further consider whether looping via `for-each` is the best way to achieve your objective; often, `apply-templates` works better to invoke relevant templates that match nodes in the input document.

---

**Update**: You can move *condition* into the `select` and still use `position() = 1` if you want the first position test to apply only to the first case where *condition* applies.

```
<xsl:for-each select="original_select_AND_CONDITION">
    <!-- do something for all cases -->
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
        <!-- do something for first case -->
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>`
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply, but the issue with position() is that I have an if condition, and it might happen that the if condition is true for the third/fourth node element. so then the position would not be 1.

Comment: Then you can move condition to be part of the `@select`; see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too vague. To take your requirement literally:

> I need to execute a piece of statement just first time when the if
>   condition is true.

you would have to do something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="some-nodes">
    <xsl:if test="condition=true()">
        <!-- DO SOMETHING -->
        <!-- if its the first entry in the if condition do something -->
        <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::some-nodes[condition=true()])">
            <!-- DO SOMETHING ADDITIONAL -->
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

which is very inefficient, as it needs to repeatedly test all the following siblings of each node.

It would be much better to process only nodes that meet the condition, then single out the first one of these, e.g.:

```
<xsl:for-each select="some-nodes[condition=true()]">
    <!-- DO SOMETHING -->
    <!-- if its the first entry in the if condition do something -->
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
        <!-- DO SOMETHING ADDITIONAL -->
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

It would probably be even better to apply templates selectively and use separate templates for each case - but we don't know enough about your purpose to tell for sure.